# mypy giving error as incompatible type "Optional[int]"; expected "Union[SupportsFloat, str, bytes, bytearray]

Tags: python, mypy

I am getting an error while running mypy `0710` version in my code. I have made a small code snippet that is having an issue but not sure why this error is appearing

```
a = None
version = 2
if version == 2:
    a = 10
    #print("asdfgh")

if float(a) == 10:
    print("erty")
```

I am getting error when I run the code in mypy as

tests/test.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "float" has incompatible type "Optional[int]"; expected "Union[SupportsFloat, str, bytes, bytearray]"

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This code would break if version is something other than 2, because then `a` is None.

Comment: @AlexHall: What will be expected type for `a`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but the point is that mypy flags `a` as an Optional[int] because it might be an int or None. The error is telling you to make sure that `a` is never None, e.g. with an else clause setting a default value.

Comment: @AlexHall: You were the first one who answered this question. I would love to accept your asnwer if you post in answer section

Comment: Nah, the posted answer is correct and the poster put in the effort of spelling out the answer properly with sample code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is that mypy does not understand that your `version` variable will *always* be exactly 2 and therefore does not understand that your first if statement will *always* run.

And if the first if statement will only sometimes run, that means that `a` will sometimes never be assigned the value 10 and will remain None. That can potentially cause a type error later on: `float(None)` is not valid.

The easiest fixes are to either drop the unnecessary if-check:

```py
a = None
version = 2
a = 10

if float(a) == 10:
    print("erty")
```

...or add in an "else" case that sets `a` to some other value if `version` is not equal to 2:

```py
a = None
version = 2
if version == 2:
    a = 10
else:
    a = 99

if float(a) == 10:
    print("erty")
```

...or to assert that `a` will be of type int:

```py
a = None
version = 2
if version == 2:
    a = 10

assert isinstance(a, int)

if float(a) == 10:
    print("erty")
```

I would personally recommend some variation of the first solution.

Comment: You saved my life!
Got some error like `Argument 1 to "float" has incompatible type "Union[float, int, str, None]"; expected "Union[SupportsFloat, SupportsIndex, str, bytes]"  [arg-type]` due to that there is possibility to reach to `float(None)` I used the last solution you suggested here.