# How to resolve incompatible type Optional type conflict?

Tags: option-type, pylint, python-3.10, union-types

Hi anyone know how to resolve this error in py3? Getting error message like:

> "int" has incompatible type "Union[float, int, str, None]"; expected
> "Union[str, bytes, SupportsInt, SupportsIndex, SupportsTrunc]

My type is an optional value `Union[float, int, str, None]`. I would like to cast it when it's an int `int(VALUE)`. Union is from `typing` module

Comment: I have a solution could be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494013/mypy-giving-error-as-incompatible-type-optionalint-expected-unionsupports I chose the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found in [mypy giving error as incompatible type "Optional[int]"; expected "Union[SupportsFloat, str, bytes, bytearray]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494013/mypy-giving-error-as-incompatible-type-optionalint-expected-unionsupports)

Example

```
  value = 10 // Type is Union[float, str, int, None], an optional value. Directly use it int(value) will trigger the error message.
  assert isinstance(value, int)
  assert int(value) == 10
```

Similar to `float` and `str`
or for the value in the list `[int(t) for t in list if isinstance(t, int)]`